# Tomcat Manager 403 Behind Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tomcat, http-status-code-403

This has been driving me crazy for a few days now. Either I'm doing something completely wrong, really silly, or a combination thereof.

I am on Ubuntu 11.10. I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
```

The following is my `tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="admin" />
  <role rolename="manager" />
  <user username="admin" password="secret" roles="admin,manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

I set up the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name tomcat.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0";
  }
}
```

Where `YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0` is `admin:secret` encoded in `Base64`.

Accessing `http://tomcat.example.com` works fine; however, whenever I try to access `http://tomcat.example.com/manager/html` I get a 403 page from Tomcat. I have tried restarting both nginx and tomcat to no avail.

The following appears in my Nginx access log whenever I try to get into the Tomcat manager:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - admin [29/Dec/2011:06:20:22 -0500] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 403 431 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7"
```

The following appears in my Tomcat access log whenever I try to get into the Tomcat manager:

```
127.0.0.1 - admin [29/Dec/2011:06:20:22 -0500] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.0" 403 1108
```

I plan to further secure this by setting up SSL on Nginx along with HTTP basic authentication, but I need to get the basics working first. Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: Does it 403 when you hit the tomcat listener directly on 8080, skipping the proxy?

Comment: Yes, I just opened up 8080 in the firewall and tried to access it directly by entering the username and password (admin, secret) into the prompt. Same result, 403.

Comment: Huh.. seems like the user config isn't working.  Any other logging in Tomcat when it fails?

Comment: Nothing that I can see. The only relevant information appears in the access logs. Where else should I look?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to try turning up some logging - add `org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL` and `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL` to your `logging.properties` file and restart Tomcat?

Comment: I've figured out what's wrong and got it working thanks to your logging suggestion. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely contradictory to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVsZq.png) from the very same installation of Tomcat, a role of simply `manager` will not suffice. I needed a role of `manager-gui`. I'm going to submit the faulty "It works!" page as a bug as this was an extremely frustrating process.

There are also other manager roles that this default "It works!" page should elaborate about, like `manager-script`.

Comment: Aha, good find!